# How to pass a value to a StaticQuery using props string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, react-props

I'm developing a site in Gatsby.js with a blog within and for a post layout, I'm coding this header with a background image to be set by the post author. I'm still in the designing phase, placing elements, blank texts etc.

I've made this component with BackgroundImage, graphQL and StaticQuery and within it's code, if I narrow the search for an image sourced from gatsby-source-filesystem with a "post_8.jpg" text, it works fine as it should.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image'
import TextScramble from './TextScramble'


const BackgroundDiv = ({ className, children }) => (
  <StaticQuery 
    query={graphql`
      query($post: String! ) {
        file(relativePath: {eq: "post_8.jpg"}) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
        }
      `
    }
    render={data => {
      const imageData = data.file.childImageSharp.fluid
      return (
        <BackgroundImage
          Tag="div"
          className={className}
          fluid={imageData}
        >
    <h1 className="bg-white shaddow shadow-md py-1 px-4 w-auto inline-block text-4xl absolute bottom-0 mb-24"><TextScramble>{ children }</TextScramble></h1>
        </BackgroundImage>
      )}
    }
  />
)

export default BackgroundDiv
```

However, I'm wondering how I would pass the value from the frontmatter from the page that contains the post, to this component.

I've been thinking on using a value passed to the component, such as a `postName`. E.g:

```js
const BackgroundDiv = ({ className, children, postName }) => (
```

Then, it would grab this value within the query in a string.

```js
query={graphql`
      query($post: String! ) {
        file(relativePath: {eq: ${postName}}) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
        }
      `
    }
```

I've made this simple addition above that didn't work. It fails on compile telling me

```
String interpolation is not allowed in graphql tag:

    9 |     query={graphql`   
   10 |       query($postName: String! ) {
 > 11 |         file(relativePath: {eq: ${postName}}) {
      |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^   
   12 |           childImageSharp {   
   13 |             fluid {   
   14 |               ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid

 File: [$pathToFolder]/gatsby-theme-cripto/src/components/backgroundDiv.js
```

I've seached for String interpolation problems on google and even ended here, but I couldn't relate those contents with my problem. I'm not a experienced dev so I believe I'm missing something. Any thoughts on this matter would be really appreciated, the same way any requests on codes I could post to help understanding this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer: You can't.

Follow the discussion on the [github repo](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10482). If you scroll all the way down, it looks like it will be available in the next few releases.

### Workaround

- Query for all the data.
- Filter for the specific data you need. You can use variables in array functions.

Here an implementation with `gatsby-image` that I use in my project

```
const Page = (props) => {
  const { data: { allFile: { edges } } } = props;
  const oneImage = edges.filter(edge => // filter with your variable
    edge.node.childImageSharp.fluid.originalName === props.yourVARIABLE)[0].node.childImageSharp.fluid;
  {/* ... */}
}
export const query = graphql`
// ...
```

---

### EDIT

In your comment, you made a mistake [destructuring your props](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-basics-of-destructuring-props-in-react-a196696f5477/) in the parameters of your arrow function. This is your revised code:

```js
const BackgroundDiv = (props) => { 
  // destructuring all the props to make it clear
  const postName = props.postName // the variable you want to filter for
  const className = props.className;
  const children = props.children;
  const { data: { allFile: { edges } } } = props; 

  const oneImage = edges.filter(edge =>  
    edge.node.childImageSharp.fluid.originalName === postName)[0].node.childImageSharp.fluid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, @EliteRaceElephant. I get it's not possible that way now. I've tried your suggestion tho. But I couldn't really understand it I guess. The code compiles as a sucess when I save the .js file but I get 'props undefined' on the browser error.
Here's the insertion I did with your suggestion:
`const BackgroundDiv = ({ className, children, props }) => {
  const { data: { allFile: { edges } } } = props;
  const oneImage = edges.filter(edge => 
    edge.node.childImageSharp.fluid.originalName === props.postName)[0].node.childImageSharp.fluid;`
Am I missing something?

Comment: Deleted previous comment because I pasted the wrong link. I meant to paste this one: https://gist.github.com/sidharthachatterjee/e0c961fd92ce287dc020939037b915ce

Comment: Please, help me with a question if you kindly will. I have a REST API with 1000 blog posts. I am now starting to useGraphQL and let go of REST. Question: From all the 1000, I need 3 for the homepage. Would it be faster to query 3 it via REST or just query all using GraphQL and filter them?

Answer (score -1):

I went through a similar issue. Luckily I found this to work with string interpolations:

```js
// Option 1
$postName
const query1 = `file(relativePath: {eq: $postName}) { ... }`

// Option 2
${({postName})

const query2 = `file(relativePath: {eq: ${({postName})}) { ... }`
```

Have a look at a snippet of code I used for one of my projects: 
 https://github.com/timrodz/.com/blob/master/src/components/common/Button/index.js#L33

Comment: Thank you so much, Juan, but I believe it wouldn't work in my case. Tried both options with no sucess. :(

Comment: string interpolation does not solve the current limitations of GraphQL in Gatsby. Follow the github discussion (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10482) for detailed answers why.